# There is no WAR *to* deploy, but I have an EAR file

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I have a Worklight project ready for deployment to a production server. I've not done this before. [The documentation states](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/devref/t_transporting_the_app.html)...

> A WAR file is created by Worklight Studio for every Worklight project, regardless of the number of apps it contains.

... but the closest my Worklight Studio (v6.2.0) is creating is an `EAR` file.

Though the file `foo.ear` does in turn hold the file `foo.war` that I was expecting, this difference with the documentation arouses deep suspicion. Are the docs out of date, or is something more fundamentally incorrect?

**Version information**:

- **Eclipse**: Luna RC3 Release (4.4.0RC3) (hmm, better get that upgraded)
- **Worklight** Studio plugins: v6.2.0.00

Comment: "There is no WAR" -- Would that it were true.

Comment: Frustratingly/Thankfully this problem is not reproducing. I restarted Eclipse, deleted the contents of the ./bin directory, deployed one of my adapters, and the WAR file was created. Hmmm.

Comment: Which goes to prove that you can always get a WAR if you try hard enough.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is up-to-date.

I would say that something in your environment is out of sync; Worklight Studio should in no way generate an .ear file; It is supposed to generate a .war file. This, in order to be fully compatible with the various supported application servers - WAS/Liberty supports .ear but Tomcat does not.

The .war file is supposed to be placed under the project-name\bin folder.

That said, an .ear file is a collection of entities (i.e., .war files), so you can simply extract the .war file from the .ear file and deploy it.

In order to figure out why you get an .ear file to begin with, ou will need to provide some more background on your environment (Eclipse version especially - it should be Eclipse Java EE), and the processes you are following.

For the record, I am using Eclipse Java EE 4.4.2 "Luna" with Worklight Studio 6.2.0.1 (from the Eclipse Marketplace), and starting Eclipse > Creating a new Worklight project > Creating a new application > deploy the application, I get a .war file in the project's bin folder.

Answer (score 0):

Once you run a build and deploy of an application or an adapter or make a change to any file under the server folder then under the bin folder you will find .wlapp, .adapter and.war files. You need to deploy the war file. If this is not the situation then there is something very wrong with your installation.